# Apply sklearn preprocessing function by groups in a pipeline

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I am trying to apply a `sklearn` preprocessing function on a per group basis in a pipeline and then remove the grouping variable.  Below is some sample code  in which I would like to apply the `StandardScaler` per group based on the variable `group1` and then drop `group1`from the pipeline. What is the best way to do this?

```
import pandas as pd
from random import choices
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
data = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['data'], columns=data['feature_names'])
df['class'] = data['target']
df['group1']=choices(['A','B','C'],k=150)
df['group2']=choices(['on','off'],k=150)
df[df.select_dtypes('object').columns.tolist()]=df.select_dtypes(['object']).apply(lambda x: x.astype('category'))

y=df['class']
X=df.drop('class',axis=1)

X_train, X_test,Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.10)
num_attribs=X_train.select_dtypes(include='number').columns.tolist()
cat_attribs=X_train.select_dtypes(include='category').columns.tolist()

num_pipeline = Pipeline([
#('imputer', Imputer(strategy="median")),
('nzv', VarianceThreshold()),
('std_scaler', StandardScaler()),
('pca', PCA(n_components=0.90, svd_solver='full')), # <- apply this on a per group basis using 'group1 then drop group1'   
])
cat_pipeline = Pipeline([
('one_hot', OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)),
])

full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
        ("num", num_pipeline, num_attribs),
        ("cat", OneHotEncoder(), cat_attribs),
    ])

X_train = full_pipeline.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = full_pipeline.transform(X_test)
```